# Need script to display Usage message if non option is chosen from menu

Tags: scripts

I have managed to get my program to function fine except for posting a usage message should the user attempt a non-menu option. The message that should be displayed if the users enter an incorrect option is line 75 `"Usage: mgr [Start|Stop|Restart|Help]"`

The script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#mgr prog
#Offers a choice of start, stop, and restart
#Executes choice then loops back to the menu

echo "==========================================" >> svclog
echo "  mgr" >> svclog
echo " mgr started " >> svclog

if [[ -f .running ]]
   then
      cat svclog
      sleep 10
fi

while [ true ]
do
   clear
   cat <<EOF

                =====
                M G R
                =====

                                $(date)

                  S -- Start svcd
                  X -- Stop svcd
                  R -- Restart svcd
                  H -- Save svclog to history file
                  I -- Help

                  q> quit

                 How may I assist you?

EOF


read ans

case $ans in
   S)  svcd
       cat svclog >> svc-hist
       rm svclog
       echo " Service starting." >> svclog
       ;;
   X)  pkill svcd
       echo " Service shutting down." >> svclog
       ;;
   R)  pkill svcd
       sleep 3
       svcd
       echo " Service has restarted." >> svclog
       ;;
   H)  cat svclog >> svc-hist
       rm svclog
       ;;
   I)  clear
       echo "
 The capital 'S' option will call the svcd file.
 The capital 'X' option will kill the svcd job.
 The capital 'R' option will kill the svcd jod, pause then call the svcd file.
 The capital 'H' option will append the svclog file log to the svc-hist file log.
 The 'I' option displays this message for 15 seconds.
 The lower case 'q' option quits this menu. "
       sleep 15
       ;;

   q)  echo " mgr stopped " >> svclog
       break
       ;;

else
   echo "Usage: mgr [Start|Stop|Restart|Help]" >> svclog

esac
done
clear
echo "
   "Louis, I think this is the beginning of a beautiful friendship."  ~Rick Blaine (Humphrey Bogart)
"
```

Comment: That is not presented as I pasted. Sorry I am going to try to paste from less:

Comment: To point out a couple of things: 1. The script you're writing has a `/bin/sh` shebang, but uses bashisms, like `[[`. 2. If you're going to use bash anyway, then you can replace the while/read loop with a `select` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
else
   echo "Usage: mgr [Start|Stop|Restart|Help]" >> svclog
esac
```

you need:

```
*) 
  echo "Usage: mgr [Start|Stop|Restart|Help]" >> svclog
esac
```

Or if you want to just print rather than saving to a file:

```
*) 
  echo "Usage: mgr [Start|Stop|Restart|Help]"
esac
```

`*)` in `case` statement means any other value other than what have been mentioned above.

[Here is a good tutorial on the usage of `case`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html).

Comment: Soon as I saw your suggestion I knew you were right Heemayl, thank you!!